# Flex: alternatingRowColors alpha color

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, colors, alpha

How to set alternatingRowColors alpah color in flex 4.6 spark DataGrid

**Answer:**

Tnx to www.Flextras.com I found it:

In the DataGrid skin need to override `prepareGridVisualElement` like this:

```
public function prepareGridVisualElement(grid:Grid, rowIndex:int, columnIndex:int):void
{
    const dataGrid:DataGrid = grid.dataGrid;
    if (!dataGrid)
        return;

    const colors:Array = dataGrid.getStyle("alternatingRowColors");
    rowBackgroundFillColor.alpha = rowIndex % 2 == 0 ? 0 : 0.25;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [alternatingRowColors](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DataGrid.html#styleSummary) or style.

To quote the docs:

> Used to initialize the DataGrid's rowBackground skin part. If the
>   alternatingRowColors style is specified, then use the
>   alternatingRowColorsBackground skin part as the value of the
>   rowBackground skin part. The alternating colors for the grid rows are
>   defined by successive entries in the Array value of this style.
>
> If you want to change how this style is rendered, replace the
>   alternatingRowColorsBackground skin part in the DataGridSkin class. If
>   you want to specify the background for each row, then initialize the
>   rowBackground skin part directly. The default value is undefined.